# Save a list of functions in Python

Tags: python, copy, closures

I have written the following code in Python where the intent is to make a list of every possible boolean function which takes arguments from the set `var_set`.  So for instance if `var_set` is `{"P","Q"}` then `all_var_evals(var_set)` should contain four functions.  One function would return `True` on input `"P"` and input `"Q"`, another would return `True` on input `"P"` but `False` on input `"Q"`, and so on.

```
def all_var_evals(var_set):
    # The bucket is an "accumulator" variable, into which I will place each evaluation as I 
    # construct them.  The bucket will then be returned at the end.
    bucket = []
    var_list = list(var_set) # Gives the variables an indexing (ordering)
    for row in range(2**(len(var_set))): # 2^n evaluations
        to_bin = row 
        func_list = []
        while to_bin != 0:
            func_list.insert(0, to_bin % 2)
            to_bin -= to_bin % 2
            to_bin //= 2
        while len(func_list) < len(var_list):
            func_list.insert(0,0)
        def f():
            return lambda x: func_list[var_list.index(x)]
        bucket.append(f())

    return bucket
```

However, after testing, I find that every function in the list seems to return `True` on every input.  I assume this is because of some kind of copy issue, like every time `func_list` takes new values, every function in the `bucket` now points to it.  I tried resolving the copy issue by making a closure, hence why it has

```
def f():
    return lambda x: func_list[var_list.index(x)]
```

However, that did not resolve the issue.  Since I've never implemented closures in Python, though, I wasn't sure how they work and after reading up on them, I still can't see how to get the desired behavior.

I also tried using `.hardcopy()` in a few different ways, none of which worked.

Comment: _I also tried using `.hardcopy()`_ What is hardcopy?  Do you mean deepcopy?

Comment: @JohnGordon Oops, that might have been the problem!

Comment: @JohnGordon Eh, after trying `copy.deepcopy()` in a few ways, that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested, but try to replace

```
        def f():
            return lambda x: func_list[var_list.index(x)]
        bucket.append(f())
```

by

```
        bucket.append(lambda x, fl=func_list: fl[var_list.index(x)])
```

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work for me. :_(

Comment: This solution works fine for me, and is exactly what I would have suggested.  Are you sure you changed `func_list` to `fl` in function definition?  (Actually, I would have used `lambda x, func_list=func_list: fuunc_list[var_list.index(x)]` but same idea.)

Comment: @FrankYellin Ooops, I'm not sure what happened -- but indeed, I just tried it again (both your way and Michael's) and now it works!  I may have typed something by mistake, I don't know.  Anyway, it's working now so thanks!

Comment: More important, do you understand why Michael did what he did and how that fixed the problem?  This is a common mistake when defining a function inside a loop that uses variables from the outside.